# Python refuses to import a module

Tags: python, pydev

There are three modules in question, in two packages:

```
Tools
   BasicLogger.py
   CascadingDataSet.py

Sandbox
   test.py
```

BasicLogger.py contains a class ('BasicLogger'), with no parents other than 'object'.

CascadingDataSet.py contains a class ('CascadingDataSet'), which is a child of BasicLogger, above.

test.py imports CascadingDataSet as follows:

```
import Tools.CascadingDataSet.CascadingDataSet as CascadingDataSet
```

(As a side note, I'm convinced I'm doing that wrong, but not only does it usually work, I can't seem to find a way to do that without repetition *somewhere*. Also, it appears to be working here.)

CascadingDataSet.py imports BasicLogger as follows:

```
import Tools.BasicLogger.BasicLogger as BasicLogger
```

This where it fails, and this is the error that I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\python\Engine\SandBox\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Tools.CascadingDataSet.CascadingDataSet as CascadingDataSheet
  File "D:\code\python\Engine\Tools\CascadingDataSet.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Tools.BasicLogger.BasicLogger as BasicLogger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tools.BasicLogger.BasicLogger'; 'Tools.BasicLogger' is not a package
```

I have tried:

- renaming the class and filename for BasicLogger.  No success.
- renaming the package itself.  No success.
- moving BasicLogger.py to a different package.  No success.
- instantiating an object of the BasicLogger class inside BasicLogger.py.  This was successful, but only confuses me more, because obviously the code itself is fine.
- creating an entirely new file, with a different name, copying the contents of BasicLogger.py into it, and trying to import that.
- importing BasicLogger directly into test.py.  Nope.
- closing and reopening the IDE.  Had to try.

My IDE (pyDev for eclipse) completely recognizes the file as an appropriate import; I even erased the import line and redid it letting pyDev autocomplete each part.  As I mentioned, the code copies fine-- but its obviously something in the code.  Either that, or I fundamentally do not understand imports at all, but I've been playing with python for like, a year, and this has never come up.

Comment: `from Tools.BasicLogger import BasicLogger`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working.  In two ways:

Two solutions:

This one was posted by deceze in the comments.

```
from Tools.BasicLogger import BasicLogger
```

This is doubly helpful because it not only solves this problem, but avoids the ridiculous threepeat, and is considerably more compact and elegant than:

```
import Tools.Logging as Logging

class CascadingDataSet(Logging.BasicLogger):
```

I'm still baffled about why it worked for CascadingDataSet but not BasicLogger, but I'm just going to let that go.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need another file outside of those two packages and also create an `__init__.py` file inside of those two packages.

```
main.py

Tools
   BasicLogger.py
   CascadingDataSet.py

Sandbox
   test.py
```

Then from `test.py` you could import it like what you write. But you couldn't run `test.py` file directly from `Sandbox` package because it can't find `Tools` packages. That's why you need `runner.py` to import and run the process from `test.py`.